# How do I make WindowDialog resizable in godot?

Tags: window, resize, godot, gdscript

So I've made this menu for my game in godot. I also made this window which shows up when a button is clicked. This window is `WindowDialog` in godot, and I want the window to be resizeable. However I get an error when I put the code for the window to be resizeable. Here is my code:

```
extends WindowDialog

var newSize

func _ready():
    # Change 'hide()' to 'show()' to show the window.
    hide()
    set_process_input(true)
    newSize = self.get_size()
    pass

func _input(event):
    if(event.type == InputEvent.MOUSE_MOTION):
        if(Input.is_mouse_button_pressed(1)):
            if (self.get_local_mouse_position().x > (self.get_size().x - 30)) && (self.get_local_mouse_position().y > (self.get_size().y - 30)) :
                newSize += event.relative_pos
                self.set_size(newSize)
                print(self.get_size().x)
                print(event.relative_x)
```

The error I get is this:

```
Invalid get index 'type' (on base: 'InputEventMouseMotion').
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question the title, to make a `WindowDialog` that can be resized, set its `resizable` to true.

---

Now, the error. Do not check a `type` property, check the type of the `event` object, like this:

```
if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
   pass
```

Or, assuming you want to read the properties of the `InputEventMouseMotion`, you can do this:

```
var mouse_motion_event := event as InputEventMouseMotion
if mouse_motion_event != null:
   pass
```

---

Something else: You probably don't need to call `set_process_input(true)`, at least not in `_ready`. If you have an `_input` function defined, Godot call it (and if it does not have `_input`, then it won't). Thus, the only reason to call `set_process_input(true)` is if you called `set_process_input(false)` before.